# regexp rewrite in condition

Tags: php, regex

I need somebody who can help me with regxp.
I explain my problem.

After a passage in ckeditor my text is like this:

```
 lorem ipsum #12345, this is a <span style="color: #111111">colored text</span>
```

I want to rewrite this text in order to transform

```
 #1234
```

in

```
<a href="/php/design/text.php?occ=1234">#1234</a>
```

I do

```
$text = preg_replace('/#([0-9]+)/', '<a href="/php/design/text.php?occ=$1">#$1</a>', $CommentText);
```

but whis this method the color code #111111 is changed too.

Can you help me writing a right regexp in order to solve my problem ( always change #1212 but not if this code is in a style attribute.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Are the numbers you are replacing out of fixed length?

Comment: This way seem to work but is not very pretty ;)

    `$text2 = preg_replace( '/([^:][ ])#([0-9]+)/', '$1<a href="/php/design/text.php?occ=$2">#$2</a>' , $text );`

Am i completelly false or this solution looks like something right?

Thanks

Comment: it should work yes, provided your CSS ALWAYS has a space between the : and the #.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's because i find my solution not very pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You just cannot do that with PHP regexes. You have to use an HTML parser to extract the *text* of the HTML document and act on it.

As you have fully well explained, you have the problem that CSS styles can contain hexadecimal color patterns (and not only `color` for that matter).

The closest solution to your problem using regexes would be negative lookbehinds, but PCRE does not support arbitrary length lookbehinds (only .NET languages do). And even if it did, you'd have to design a regex to match *all* possible cases.

Don't do that. Use an HTML parser and match your regex (which pretty much works) against the text content only.

Comment: hmmm, a solution i've not think about. Thanks. I will have a look at this solution. Perhaps the best for me, yes. After a look on google, i find this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/. I will try.

Comment: I have modified my code (remplace # with id) and learn the usage of negative lookbehinds (replace when no </a> exist after id1234): works perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try conditional subpattern based regex code like this:

```
$CommentText = 'lorem ipsum #12345, this is a <span style="color: #12345">colored text</span>';
$r = "~#(12345).*?((<)(?(3)[^>]*>))~i";
$s = preg_replace($r, "<a href='/php/design/text.php?occ=$1'>#$1</a>$2", $CommentText);
echo "$s\n";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
lorem ipsum <a href='/php/design/text.php?occ=12345'>#12345</a><span style="color: #12345">colored text</span>
```

Comment: Conditional Subpattern Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. I'll try tomorrow (no more time today)